# Reporting error in jsf using tag onerror in menuitem tag

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to jsf and want raise a dialog box with Error in primefaces (using jsf 2) using tag "onerror" in following xhtml code

```
<h:form>
<p:growl id="errorgrowl"  autoUpdate="true" life="5000" severity="error,fatal"/>
..
..
    <p:submenu label="${messages.mLinkView}">
        <p:menuitem value="${messages.mShowOnMap}" target="_blank" outcome="#{linkViewController.showLinkView(nobListController.csvParser,nobListController.allNobMan)}" update="errorgrowl"/>
        <p:menuitem value="${messages.mShowPhyLinksOnMap}" target="_blank" outcome="#{linkViewController.showPhyLinkView(nobListController.csvParserPhyLinks,nobListController.allNobMan)}" update="errorgrowl" />
    </p:submenu>
```

java:
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.error ("prepareNElistPhyLinks() Failed to compute MPLS-Xc Links" + 
                        ((e instanceof GeneralException) ? ((GeneralException)e).reason : e.getMessage ()));
                e.printStackTrace ();
                FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
            }

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can report through [p:growl](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml)

```
<h:form> 
   <p:growl id="errorgrowl"  autoUpdate="true" life="5000" severity="error,fatal"/>
 ...
<h:form>
```

In bean :

```
try {
    ...
}catch(Exception e) {
  FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
    // FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed(); may need this also
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.
I made changes suggested by you. But it is not working.
 <h:form>
 <p:growl id="errorgrowl"  autoUpdate="true" life="5000" severity="error,fatal"/>
....
 <p:submenu label="${messages.mLinkView}">
   <p:menuitem value="${messages.mShowOnMap}" target="_blank" outcome="#{linkViewController.showLinkView(nobListController.csvParser,nobListController.allNobMan)}"/>